# Squares in Lucas sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, integer-sequences, recurrences, elementary-proofs

Good night, everyone!

According to a celebrated result by J. H. Cohn, the only perfect squares in the Fibonacci sequence are $F_{0}=0$, $F_{1}=F_{2}=1$, and $F_{12}=144$. It is also known that the only perfect squares in the [Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) are $L_{1}=1$ and $L_{3}=4$.

Do you know other (interesting) examples of [Lucas sequences](http://oeis.org/wiki/Lucas_sequences) with few perfect squares among their terms? I am specially interested in examples in which the determination of the squares is more straightforward than Cohn's proof of the aforementioned theorem.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You may like to check my paper [On Integral Points on Biquadratic Curves and Near-Multiples of Squares in Lucas Sequences](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL17/Alekseyev/alekseyev3.html) although it's more of computational rather than analytical nature.

Comment: I don't know what you consider *interesting*. $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are Lucas sequences with very easy proofs of rarity of squares.

Comment: The main branch of the Collatz conjecture $1,5,21,85,\ldots=\frac{4^n-1}3$ is a Lucas sequence which factors into $\frac{(2^n-1)(2^n+1)}{3}$ and since these differ from a perfect square by $1$ I can't see this sequence containing many squares.

Answer (score 7):

I will give a few references which could be considered as some answer to this question. Though the matter of "straight forward" is up to interpretation. Furthermore, I am far from any kind of expert on these sequences. I have written a paper on (some combinatorial aspects of) Lucas sequences and remember some references from when I was reading up on them.

First there are a lot of second order linear reccurences which have few (= finitely many) perfect square terms. In [Perfect powers in second order linear recurrences](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(82)90079-8) by Pethö a special case of the main theorem says that for a second order linear recurrence $G_n = AG_{n-1} - BG_{n-2}$ there are only finitely many perfect square terms provided some conditions. The conditions are that $A \neq 0$, $|G_0| + |G_1| \neq 0$, $\gcd(A,B) = 1$, $A^2 \neq iB$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, and $D$ is not a perfect square if $BC = 0$. Here $C = G_1^2 - AG_0G_1 + BG_1^2$ and $D = A^2 - 4B$. This paper gives some bounds on where perfect squares can arise by Baker’s method, but since Lucas sequences are special one may want to know more.

In [The Square Terms in Lucas Sequences](https://doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1996.0068) by Ribenboim and McDaniel is in shown more precisely where perfect square terms can arise in Lucas sequences under some conditions. Under the conditions that $P$ and $Q$ are odd, $\gcd(P,Q) = 1$, and $D = P^2 - 4Q > 0$ it is shown that

- if $V_n(P,Q)$ is a perfect square, then $n \in \{1,3,5\}$.
- if $U_n(P,Q)$ is a perfect square, then $n \in \{0,1,2,3,6,12\}$.

Here the notation matches with the usual notation which is given the OEIS link "Lucas sequences" in the question. We see this result agrees with what is known for $F_n$ and $L_n$. Again I am not an expert, but I think exactly where squares occur depends on particular choices of $P$ and $Q$ and I am not familiar with particular of methods used in various cases. You can find more papers like [Lucas sequences whose 12th or 9th term is a square](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405306)
 by Bremner and Tzanakis. Looking at these papers with their references + google scholar gives more information on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most known Lucas sequences, after the Fibonacci and the Lucas numbers, is the sequence of Pell numbers:
$P_n=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{if }n=0;\\1&\mbox{if }n=1;\\2P_{n-1}+P_{n-2}&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

The sequence of Pell numbers starts with $0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, 2378$. [It is known](https://arato.inf.unideb.hu/petho.attila/cikkek/PELL2_44.pdf) that the only squares in this sequence are 1 and 169. Furthemore, there are no higher powers of integers.