# Finding all squares in a generalized Fibonacci type sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory

I asked this two weeks ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571697/squares-in-a-second-order-integer-recursive-sequence

Most of the related question shown to me while composing are about primes, not squares...

Given a sequence $x_n$ as in https://oeis.org/A001075
$$  1, 2, 7, 26, 97, 362, 1351,   $$
such that
$$ x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n $$

These are the $x$ values in $x^2-3y^2 = 1$

Can we find, and prove, all squares in the sequence and all double squares? 
I see that Cohn did this for the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers in the 1960's. 
**For this sequence, it seems $1$ is the only square and $2$ is the only doubled square.**

alright, an answer at the recent [Squares in Lucas sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342483/squares-in-lucas-sequences)  does give a [reference Petho](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X82900798?via%3Dihub)

Comment: Is this sequence somehow special? (and why?)

Answer (score 2):

CW. this turns out to be  a question from May 2020 in a Hungarian magazine for high school students; a bit deflating. The deadline was June 10th and an answer became available online; they did squares but did not bother with twice squares.

[image]